# Script doesn't work on child page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I don't know why my JQuery code doesn't work if I use it on my child page to transfer text of the rows selected from the table to the parent or opener page. Rows on the table is loaded using AJAX.

If I try to create a table, set its rows and td on the HTML file itself, and use the the JQuery code, it works. How is that?

Here are my codes of HTML, AJAX, Scripts

**HTML**

```html
<body onload="showDetails()">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 30px;">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <center>
          <h2>Products</h2>
        </center>
        <br/>
        <table id="products-table" class="table table-hover">
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function showDetails() {
      var xmlhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("products-table").innerHTML =
                                                        xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("POST", "product.php", true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
  </script>
  <script src="q.js"></script>
```

**PHP**

```
 echo '<tr>
        <th>Image</th> 
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Terms</th>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th></th>
 </tr>';
 try {
     $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mfcwebsitedb', 'root', 'pass@word1');
     foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from products') as $row) 
     {
        echo '<tr> 
            <td class = "img">'.'<img src = "product-img/'.$row['img_name'].'" style = "width: 200px; height: 200px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">'.'</td>
            <td class = "brand">'.$row['brand'].'</td>
            <td class = "model">'.$row['model'].'</td>
            <td class = "price">'.$row['price'].'</td>
            <td class = "terms">'.$row['terms'].'</td>
            <td class = "class">'.$row['class'].'</td>
            <td><button class = "btn btn-primary selectbtn">Select</button></td>
          </tr>';
     }

 $dbh = null;
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
    $dbh = null;
 }
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#products-table .selectbtn').click(function() {

        var td = $(this).closest('tr');

        var f;
        var s;
        var t;
        var q;
        var w;
        var g;

        $(td).each(function(){
            f = $(this).find(".class").html(); 
            s = $(this).find(".brand").html(); 
            t = $(this).find(".model").html(); 
            q = $(this).find(".price").html(); 
            w = $(this).find(".terms").html(); 
            g = $(this).find(".img").html(); 
        });

        var x = 'Class: ' + f + '\n' + 'Brand: ' + s + '\n' 
                + 'Model: ' + t + '\n'
                + 'Price: ' + q + '\n' + 'Terms: ' + w;
        var z = g + '<br/>' + '<b>Class:</b> ' + f + '<br/>\n' 
                + '<b>Brand: </b>' + s + '<br/>\n' 
                + '<b>Model: </b>' + t + '<br/>\n' 
                + '<b>Price: </b>' + q + '<br/>\n' + '<b>Terms: </b>' + w;
        opener.document.motorappform.productdesc.value = x;
        opener.document.motorappform.productdeschidden.value = z;
        self.close();
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use event delegation to catch dynamically created elements:

```
$(document).on('click', '#products-table .selectbtn', function() {
   // your code here ..
});
```

**EDIT**

Also, inside your function, store `$(this)` in a variable and use this variable instead of instantiating it more that once:

(use `td` instead of `$(td)`)

```
td.each(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    f = that.find(".class").html(); 
    s = that.find(".brand").html(); 
    t = that.find(".model").html(); 
    q = that.find(".price").html(); 
    w = that.find(".terms").html(); 
    g = that.find(".img").html(); 
});
```

Comment: No, you should replace $('#products-table .selectbtn').click(function() { ... }); with that